# I compiled my kivy application shows blank when compiled to android app using buildozer

Tags: android, kivy

One confusing thing is the assets is compiled as private.mp3. I extracted the apk, manually loaded the asset files, created and signed the certificates but still no head way. What am I doing wrongly?

**This is the APP part of the code**

```
class J6classicpuzzlegameApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.title = 'J6 Classic Puzzle Game Version 1.0 - Trial Version'
        self.initialise_global_vars()
        db = DragButton()
        db.data_folder = os.path.join(self.initialise_global_vars(), 'data')
        db.custom_folder = os.path.join(self.initialise_global_vars(), 
         'custom')
        db.back_folder = os.path.join(self.initialise_global_vars(), 'back')
        db.withnum_folder = 
        os.path.join(self.initialise_global_vars(),'withnum')
        db.imgsource = os.path.join(db.custom_folder,'custom.imgsource.png')
        Factory.register('Root', cls=Root)
        Factory.register('LoadDialog', cls=LoadDialog)
        Factory.register('SaveDialog', cls=SaveDialog)
        sys.stderr = open('output.txt', 'w')
        sys.stdout = sys.stderr
        print('\n'.join([str(l) for l in LoggerHistory.history]))
        return DragButton()
    
    def initialise_global_vars(self):
    
        root_folder = self.user_data_dir
        cache_folder = os.path.join(root_folder, path)
        return cache_folder
   

    #if not os.path.exists(cache_folder):
        #os.makedirs(cache_folder)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    J6classicpuzzlegameApp().run()
```

'''
Buildozer.spec

```
    # (str) Title of your application
title = J6 Classic Puzzle Game

# (str) Package name
package.name = J6classicpuzzlegame

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = com.j6classicpuzzlegame

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = 

# (list) List of inclusions using pattern matching
source.include_patterns =

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_exts = spec

# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin, dist, build

# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
#source.exclude_pattern = setup

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
version = 1.0

# (str) Application versioning (method 2)
#version.regex = __version__ = ['"](.*)['"]
#version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py

# (list) Application requirements
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python3,kivy,AudioPlayer,pygame

# (str) Custom source folders for requirements
# Sets custom source for any requirements with recipes
# requirements.source.kivy = ../../kivy

# (list) Garden requirements
#garden_requirements =

# (str) Presplash of the application
presplash.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/GamePic2.png

# (str) Icon of the application
icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/gameicon.png

# (str) Supported orientation (one of landscape, sensorLandscape, portrait or all)
orientation = all

# (list) List of service to declare
#services = NAME:ENTRYPOINT_TO_PY,NAME2:ENTRYPOINT2_TO_PY

#
# OSX Specific
#

#
author = © Copyright Jonathan Olorunleke Olukotun

# change the major version of python used by the app
osx.python_version = 3

# Kivy version to use
#osx.kivy_version = 1.11.1

#
# Android specific
#

# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
fullscreen =  False

# (string) Presplash background color (for new android toolchain)
# Supported formats are: #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB or one of the following names:
# red, blue, green, black, white, gray, cyan, magenta, yellow, lightgray,
# darkgray, grey, lightgrey, darkgrey, aqua, fuchsia, lime, maroon, navy,
# olive, purple, silver, teal.
#android.presplash_color = aqua

# (list) Permissions
android.permissions = INTERNET,WAKE_LOCK, ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE


# (int) Target Android API, should be as high as possible.
android.api = 29


# (int) Minimum API your APK will support.
android.minapi = 21

# (int) Android SDK version to use
#android.sdk = 20

# (str) Android NDK version to use
#android.ndk = 19b

# (int) Android NDK API to use. This is the minimum API your app will support, it should usually match android.minapi.
#android.ndk_api = 21

# (bool) Use --private data storage (True) or --dir public storage (False)
android.private_storage = True

# (str) Android NDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ndk_path =

# (str) Android SDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.sdk_path =

# (str) ANT directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ant_path =

# (bool) If True, then skip trying to update the Android sdk
# This can be useful to avoid excess Internet downloads or save time
# when an update is due and you just want to test/build your package
# android.skip_update = False

# (bool) If True, then automatically accept SDK license
# agreements. This is intended for automation only. If set to False,
# the default, you will be shown the license when first running
# buildozer.
# android.accept_sdk_license = False

# (str) Android entry point, default is ok for Kivy-based app
android.entrypoint = org.renpy.android.PythonActivity

# (str) Android app theme, default is ok for Kivy-based app
# android.apptheme = "@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"

# (list) Pattern to whitelist for the whole project
#android.whitelist =

# (str) Path to a custom whitelist file
#android.whitelist_src =

# (str) Path to a custom blacklist file
#android.blacklist_src =

# (list) List of Java .jar files to add to the libs so that pyjnius can access
# their classes. Don't add jars that you do not need, since extra jars can slow
# down the build process. Allows wildcards matching, for example:
# OUYA-ODK/libs/*.jar
#android.add_jars = foo.jar,bar.jar,path/to/more/*.jar

# (list) List of Java files to add to the android project (can be java or a
# directory containing the files)
#android.add_src =

# (list) Android AAR archives to add (currently works only with sdl2_gradle
# bootstrap)
#android.add_aars =

# (list) Gradle dependencies to add (currently works only with sdl2_gradle
# bootstrap)
#android.gradle_dependencies =

# (list) add java compile options
# this can for example be necessary when importing certain java libraries using the 'android.gradle_dependencies' option
# see https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support for further information
# android.add_compile_options = "sourceCompatibility = 1.8", "targetCompatibility = 1.8"

# (list) Gradle repositories to add {can be necessary for some android.gradle_dependencies}
# please enclose in double quotes 
# e.g. android.gradle_repositories = "maven { url 'https://kotlin.bintray.com/ktor' }"
#android.add_gradle_repositories =

# (list) packaging options to add 
# see https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.PackagingOptions.html
# can be necessary to solve conflicts in gradle_dependencies
# please enclose in double quotes 
# e.g. android.add_packaging_options = "exclude 'META-INF/common.kotlin_module'", "exclude 'META-INF/*.kotlin_module'"
#android.add_gradle_repositories =

# (list) Java classes to add as activities to the manifest.
#android.add_activities = com.example.ExampleActivity

# (str) OUYA Console category. Should be one of GAME or APP
# If you leave this blank, OUYA support will not be enabled
#android.ouya.category = GAME

# (str) Filename of OUYA Console icon. It must be a 732x412 png image.
#android.ouya.icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/ouya_icon.png

# (str) XML file to include as an intent filters in <activity> tag
#android.manifest.intent_filters =

# (str) launchMode to set for the main activity
android.manifest.launch_mode = standard

#(list) Android additional libraries to copy into libs/armeabi
#android.add_libs_armeabi = libs/android/*.so
#android.add_libs_armeabi_v7a = libs/android-v7/*.so
#android.add_libs_arm64_v8a = libs/android-v8/*.so
#android.add_libs_x86 = libs/android-x86/*.so
#android.add_libs_mips = libs/android-mips/*.so

# (bool) Indicate whether the screen should stay on
# Don't forget to add the WAKE_LOCK permission if you set this to True
#android.wakelock = False

# (list) Android application meta-data to set (key=value format)
#android.meta_data =

# (list) Android library project to add (will be added in the
# project.properties automatically.)
#android.library_references =

# (list) Android shared libraries which will be added to AndroidManifest.xml using <uses-library> tag
#android.uses_library =

# (str) Android logcat filters to use
android.logcat_filters = *:S python:D

# (bool) Copy library instead of making a libpymodules.so
android.copy_libs = 1

# (str) The Android arch to build for, choices: armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86, x86_64
android.arch = armeabi-v7a

# (int) overrides automatic versionCode computation (used in build.gradle)
# this is not the same as app version and should only be edited if you know what you're doing
# android.numeric_version = 1

#
# Python for android (p4a) specific
#

# (str) python-for-android fork to use, defaults to upstream (kivy)
#p4a.fork = kivy

# (str) python-for-android branch to use, defaults to master
#p4a.branch = master

# (str) python-for-android git clone directory (if empty, it will be automatically cloned from github)
#p4a.source_dir =

# (str) The directory in which python-for-android should look for your own build recipes (if any)
#p4a.local_recipes =

# (str) Filename to the hook for p4a
#p4a.hook =

# (str) Bootstrap to use for android builds
p4a.bootstrap = sdl2

# (int) port number to specify an explicit --port= p4a argument (eg for bootstrap flask)
#p4a.port =


#
# iOS specific
#

# (str) Path to a custom kivy-ios folder
#ios.kivy_ios_dir = ../kivy-ios
# Alternately, specify the URL and branch of a git checkout:
#ios.kivy_ios_url = https://github.com/kivy/kivy-ios
#ios.kivy_ios_branch = master

# Another platform dependency: ios-deploy
# Uncomment to use a custom checkout
#ios.ios_deploy_dir = ../ios_deploy
# Or specify URL and branch
#ios.ios_deploy_url = https://github.com/phonegap/ios-deploy
#ios.ios_deploy_branch = 1.7.0

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the debug version
# Get a list of available identities: buildozer ios list_identities
#ios.codesign.debug = "iPhone Developer: <lastname> <firstname> (<hexstring>)"

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the release version
#ios.codesign.release = %(ios.codesign.debug)s


[buildozer]

# (int) Log level (0 = error only, 1 = info, 2 = debug (with command output))
log_level = 2

# (int) Display warning if buildozer is run as root (0 = False, 1 = True)
warn_on_root = 1

# (str) Path to build artifact storage, absolute or relative to spec file
# build_dir = ./.buildozer

# (str) Path to build output (i.e. .apk, .ipa) storage
# bin_dir = ./bin

#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    List as sections
#
#    You can define all the "list" as [section:key].
#    Each line will be considered as a option to the list.
#    Let's take [app] / source.exclude_patterns.
#    Instead of doing:
#
#[app]
#source.exclude_patterns = license,data/audio/*.wav,data/images/original/*
#
#    This can be translated into:
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns]
#license
#data/audio/*.wav
#data/images/original/*
#


#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    Profiles
#
#    You can extend section / key with a profile
#    For example, you want to deploy a demo version of your application without
#    HD content. You could first change the title to add "(demo)" in the name
#    and extend the excluded directories to remove the HD content.
#
#[app@demo]
#title = My Application (demo)
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns@demo]
#images/hd/*
#
#    Then, invoke the command line with the "demo" profile:
#
#buildozer --profile demo android debug
```

Comment: Does your code work on your PC? What do you see if you run `buildozer -v android debug deploy run logcat` with your android device connected to your PC?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The app is a puzzle game. It run on Windows and Linux without any issue. I will get back to you on the second part soon

Comment: After running the command - buildozer -v android debug deploy run logcat                                      I notice this info. Could it possible point to the issue I'm facing? Unable to strip library '1' due to error /root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-strip returned from '/home/jonathan/J6ClassicPuzzleGame/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/J6classicpuzzlegame__armeabi-v7a/build/intermediates/transforms/mergeJniLibs/debug/0/lib/armeabi-v7a/gdb.setup', packaging it as is.